# How to improve huge Logstash "If Statement"

Tags: logstash

My logstash instance is reading in sysmon events (shipped in json from nxlog) and will store them in elasticsearch after I manipulate some fields.

I want to create a new field with the value based on the sysmon event type.  I can use the field [Task] to determine which sysmon event I'm receiving (1 through 9).  But I'm ending up with this huge if/else statement.

I'd rather be able to establish some local array:

```
EventObject=>['process','file','flow','sysmon']
```

Then, create a new field with something like

```
mutate { add_field => {"object" => EventObject[$Task]}}
```

Rather, I have this

```
if [Task] == 1 { 
       mutate {
        add_field => {"object" => "process"}
       }


   } else if [Task] == 2 {
   mutate{
      add_field => {"object" => "file"}  

   } else if [Task] == 3 {
   mutate{
      add_field => {"object" => "flow"}  

   } else if [Task] == 4 {
         etc....
enter code here
```

What is the right way to do this?  I am trying to make my logstash config easy to read and reduce the number of lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the [translate filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-translate.html).